# How can I sync my Google Work Calendar with my Android Phone

Tags: calendar

I don't want to add my Gmail(Work) on my phone because it requires all those device admin profiles and the Admin controlling that will control my phone.

I've managed to sync work emails via IMAP in the Gmail App, now I have issues with the calendar. Is there a way to sync the gmail work calender?

eg myname@mycompany.com (Google Apps for Work) Calender with my Android Device.

I know I can share the calendar with my personal account and then access it, but is there a way I can add that calender to my phone?

I see there is an Exchange Account on Android 5.1 would that do the job?

Comment: If you share the work@gmail.com calendar with private@gmail.com account (like you did), you should be able to see the sub-calendar @work in your calendar-app. (In settings `Calendars to display`)

Comment: i see the sub calendar but i cannot make changes to it ( edit events ) because of the security settings. That's why i need a dedicated app where i can login using my email credentials and manage the calendar sync from there.

Comment: The access-type for sharing to the work-calendar should be set to `Make changes to event`. If that is not done (or can't be done) you can't change events through your private account. I'm not aware of any Android calendar-apps which have a "stand-alone" calendar accounts. They all add the account to Android itself. (You can limit that account to only sync the calendar though) Otherwise you would need to login via a browser and use the web-interface but you'll loose notification etc.